# im working on getting a connect wallet button functioning but i keep getting an error

Tags: solidity, web3js, wallets, cpp-ethereum

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";
import {providers} from "ethers";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import web3Modal from "web3modal";

export default function Home() {
  const [walletConnected, setWalletConnected] = useState(false);

  const web3ModalRef = useRef();

  const connectWallet = async () => {
    await getProviderOrSigner();
    setWalletConnected(true);

    // update wallet connected to be true
  };
  const getproviderOrSigner = async (needSigner = false) => {
    //we need to gain access to the signer/provider from metamask
    const provider = await web3ModalRef.current.connect();
    //this line above pops up metamask
    const web3Provider = new providers.web3Provider(provider);

    //if the user is not connected to rinkeby, tell them to switch to rinkeby
    const { chainId } = await web3Provider.getNetwork();
    if (chainId !== 4) {
      window.alert("Please switch to the Rinkeby Network");
      throw new Error("Incorrect Network");
    }

    if (needSigner) {
      const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
      return signer;
    }

    return web3Provider;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!walletConnected) {
      web3ModalRef.current = new web3Modal({
        network: "rinkeby",
        providerOptions: {},
        disableInjectedProvider: false,
      });

      connectWallet();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Crypto Devs NFT</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.main}>
        {walletConnected ? (
          <button onClick={connectWallet} className={styles.button}>
            Connect Wallet
          </button>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}






error //
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: getproviderOrSigner is not defined

Source
pages\index.js (47:6) @ eval

  45 |       });
  46 | 
> 47 |       connectWallet();
     |      ^
  48 |     }
  49 |   }, []);
  50 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an error because I didn’t use the camel casing correctly for getProviderOrSigner. I have effected the correction but I still get a blank screen on my server